# Gosund dimmer connects but light fixture not being powered

Tags: dimmer-switch

I installed a Gosund dimmer today and while the connections seem to be correct, the lights are not being powered on, so power to the fixture is not occurring. The dimmer turns on and connects to the app (is also recognized) but again, my power source isn't working. I don't have a voltage meter but am sure the black is live and white is neutral as that was how it was installed before I put this dimmer in (The red was wrapped around the joint wiring in the box). Also, I switched out the lights to be "dimmer lightbulbs" on the fixture. What am I doing wrong?[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of how the light fixture is wired please?

Comment: How was the old dimmer wired?

Comment: Are you certain all of the wiring is tightly secured in the wire nuts? Hold each nut and tug (individually) on each of the wires to ensure that none are loose.